# Read warranty expiration date on iOS

Tags: ios, function

Is there an iOS function that I can call to read the warranty expiration date of an iPhone?

Regards,

Martin

Comment: quite easy: if the screen breaks or the battery dies — the day before warranty expired.

Comment: Unfortunately No
# Version 2.1
# Apple has again changed the warranty lookup method and now redirects to
# a CAPTCHA protected page at https://checkcoverage.apple.com/
# As such, no "online" warranty status is now possible. All warranty
# information is now estimated.